# new java question not showing up in newest questions, but in homepage

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, homepage, newest-questions

I notice that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319510/java-language-design-with-tostring) is showing up on the homepage, but not on the newest java questions. Can someone fix this soon?

This question is in fact a recurrence of my other question with the same name.

Answer (score 5):

It's not showing up in Newest because it isn't new - it was asked three years ago. It showed up on the homepage because someone edited it.

Comment: @animuson: Side question: How can we write summery for rollback same as you did here?

Comment: @hims Hit "edit" instead of "rollback," type a message, submit

Comment: @Doorknob - Yes that's true. But I think we can achieve this by rollback too. Because I have see lots of users who have rolled-back with summery.

Comment: @hims056 It does the same thing, actually.

Comment: @Doorknob - Oh I got it. You mean edit previous revision (which we want to rollback). Thanks. :)